# Wiping Windows 10 to OOBE without losing programs and drivers?

Tags: windows-10

I have an old laptop machine that I wish to sell. Usually I would just wipe it clean but many of the drivers are difficult to install (need to be installed manually and in specific order) and I just don't want the hassle of having to explain all this to a potential new owner over eBay messaging. I currently have the machine running a freshly installed Windows 10 with all drivers setup and working flawlessly. How can I reset it to the out of box experience so the potential new owner can add their user and settings without having to go through all the driver installation?

Answer (score 1):

Windows by default now comes with a utility for just this purpose. It's called Sysprep.

Go to C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep. Run the utility and set the system cleanup action to OOBE.

I'd like to add, do not select the 'generalize' option as it strips drivers and the SID to prepare an image for different PCs.